# Is there a difference between sources of damage?

Tags: damage-types, the-void

The Void has many similarities with the Storyteller and Storytelling systems. But a few things just stop making sense sometimes.

A SM-12 Hornet (SMG) shot deals 1d6 damage, but a baseball bat deals 3d6 damage.
So... What's that all about? If there was anything as bashing or lethal damage, this could make sense... The thing is... Is there?

Answer (score 1):

In The Void, automatic weapons fired on auto inflict a number of *additional* damage dice as listed in the auto column of the weapon and consume the amount of ammo listed in parenthesis. The "hornet" has an auto rating of 6(60 rounds). When firing full auto you must score one additional success than needed to inflict the auto damage. For the "hornet" if you hit in auto mode, you would inflict 7d6 damage! This also consumes 60 rounds in that attack (one full magazine)!

Remember: each success you score in addition to the target number, you inflict an additional die of damage - for auto fire, you need one additional success for the +6 damage dice, then each additional success adds another die. Also, for the baseball bat, you get one additional die of damage for every two points you have in physique.